# NullPointerException to fill JTextField through a search for another screen

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

Good Afternoon!
I'm having trouble with `NullPointerException`  when I try to load data into the registration screen after the choice of the desired record in another search screen.
My codes.:
SearchScreen:

```
public int retornaSelecao() {
    return (int) tablePesquisa.getValueAt(tablePesquisa.getSelectedRow(), 0);
}
private void tablePesquisaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                           
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
         CadastroCliente cliente = new CadastroCliente(this.retornaSelecao());
         this.dispose();
    }
}
```

this screen I get the id of the record in `JTable` and call screen registers as passing the id parameter

Now the Registrtion Screen

```
public CadastroCliente() {
    initComponents();
    this.desabilitaCampos();
    btnAlterar.setEnabled(false);
    btnExcluir.setEnabled(false);
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(false);
    btnSalvar.setEnabled(false);
    btnNovo.setEnabled(true);
    btnPesquisa.setEnabled(true);
    btnSair.setEnabled(true);    
}

public CadastroCliente(int codigo){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTE WHERE CODIGO = " + codigo;
    Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
    ResultSet rst;
    //System.out.println("" + codigo);
    try {
        pstm = conexao.conectar().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM CLIENTE WHERE CODIGO = '" + codigo + "';");
        rst = pstm.executeQuery();
        while (rst.next()) {
            txtCodigo.setText("" + rst.getString("codigo"));
            System.out.println("" + rst.getString("codigo"));
            txtDataCadastro.setText(rst.getDate("datacadastro").toString());
            txtDataNascimento.setDate(rst.getDate("datanascimento"));
            txtNome.setText(rst.getString("nome").toUpperCase());
            txtApelido.setText(rst.getString("apelido").toUpperCase());
            txtEndereco.setText(rst.getString("endereco").toUpperCase());
            txtNumero.setText(rst.getString("numero"));
            txtComplemento.setText(rst.getString("complemento").toUpperCase());
            txtBairro.setText(rst.getString("bairro").toUpperCase());
            txtCep.setText(rst.getString("cep"));
            txtNomeCidade.setText(rst.getString("cidade").toUpperCase());
            txtRg.setText(rst.getString("rg"));
            txtCpf.setText(rst.getString("cpf"));
            cbPagamento.setSelectedItem(rst.getInt("diapagamento"));
            txtMensalidade.setText("" + rst.getFloat("mensalidade"));
            txtTelefoneResidencial.setText(rst.getString("telres"));
            txtTelefoneComercial.setText(rst.getString("telcom"));
            txtTelefoneCelular.setText(rst.getString("celular"));
            txtInformacoes.setText(rst.getString("informacoes"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CadastroCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new CadastroCliente().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I created two constructors are giving more `NullPointerException` while after the first is completed where the `JTextField`. Why is giving this error? Can anyone help me? thank you

Comment: The stacktrace please. And the line in which the NP-Exception occurs.

Comment: You have nowhere initialized the Textfield in your code. Have you initialized those textfields ?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at br.com.erp.cliente.CadastroCliente.<init>(CadastroCliente.java:56)
 at br.com.erp.cliente.PesquisaCliente.tablePesquisaMouseClicked(PesquisaCliente.java:275)
 at br.com.erp.cliente.PesquisaCliente.access$700(PesquisaCliente.java:19)

Answer (score 2):

It would help to post a stacktrace and the line on which the error is occuring.

But by looking at the 2 constructors:

```
public CadastroCliente() {
    initComponents();
    this.desabilitaCampos();
    btnAlterar.setEnabled(false);
    btnExcluir.setEnabled(false);
    btnCancelar.setEnabled(false);
    btnSalvar.setEnabled(false);
    btnNovo.setEnabled(true);
    btnPesquisa.setEnabled(true);
    btnSair.setEnabled(true);
}

public CadastroCliente(int codigo){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTE WHERE CODIGO = " + codigo;
    Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
    ResultSet rst;
    ...
}
```

you dont call methods like `initComponents()` in your `CadastroCliente(int codigo)` constructor which most likely initializes your GUI (and most `JTextField` etc).

it should be:

```
public CadastroCliente(int codigo){
    initComponents();//initialize components
     //if the buttons need to be set do that here
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTE WHERE CODIGO = " + codigo;
    Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
    ResultSet rst;
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Also you do not want to do long running Task like database queries on GUIs Event Dispatch Thread as this may cause the UI to *freeze* and only become active after the task has completed thus no intermediary results will be shown:

```
ResultSet rst;
//System.out.println("" + codigo);
try {
    pstm = conexao.conectar().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM CLIENTE WHERE CODIGO = '" + codigo + "';");
    rst = pstm.executeQuery();
    while (rst.next()) {
        txtCodigo.setText("" + rst.getString("codigo"));//wont show until the while loop is done
        ...
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CadastroCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Its best too offload this work to a [Swing Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and use its [`publish(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish%28V...%29) method to get intermediate results.

[As per Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html):

> SwingWorker provides a number of communication and control features:
>
> - The SwingWorker subclass can define a method, done, which is automatically invoked on the event dispatch thread when the background
>     task is finished.
> - SwingWorker implements java.util.concurrent.Future. This interface allows the background task to provide a return value to the other
>     thread. Other methods in this interface allow cancellation of the
>     background task and discovering whether the background task has
>     finished or been cancelled.
> - The background task can provide intermediate results by invoking SwingWorker.publish, causing SwingWorker.process to be invoked from
>     the event dispatch thread.
> - The background task can define bound properties. Changes to these properties trigger events, causing event-handling methods to be
>     invoked on the event dispatch thread.

Also have a read on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Hello David Kroukamp, I put the initComponents () constructor in the second, and really did not give the error nullpointer exception, making it more data are not placed in the JTextField, they are blank, and gives no error. I put a System.out.println () and data were displayed on the console. Because such data are not filled in JTextField?
thank you

Comment: *I put the initComponents () constructor in the second, and really did not give the error nullpointer exception* so no more NPE? *making it more data are not placed in the JTextField, they are blank, and gives no error* So the data which you are filling JtextFields with from the ResultSet is not showing? does it eventually show after the database query has finished?

Comment: Does the data you are trying to populate JTextField show up after database query `while (rst.next()) {
            txtCodigo.setText("" + rst.getString("codigo"));...}` has done excuting

Comment: So why when I put a System.out.println in the same place jtexfield the right? Do you have any suggestions for me to solve this problem?

Comment: Read my update again added some stuff... you would use publish method of Swing Worker. See the links on the words highlighted with blue that should give you all you need